# How do you save a txt file with JFileChooser

Tags: java

Hey im trying to make a notepad type program and I can't save the file can you help?

```
save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            saveFile();

            if(fileToSave == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                try{
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Save.getSelectedFile().getPath() + ".txt"));

                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    });

public void saveFile(){
        JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser();
        int option = save.showSaveDialog(this);
        fileToSave = option;
        Save = save;
    }
```

Comment: `can't save the file` can you describe it more? Do you see some errors/exceptions? Also how does `saveFile` method code looks like? What is and where is initialized `fileToSave`?

Comment: It just creates a blank file

Comment: and i just added the saveFile method

Comment: Well, I don't see any code using your `BufferedWriter out`. Why would you expect it to write data to file if it doesn't know which data it should use?

Comment: I am new at this and i was following a tutorial

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/ for examples of how to pass data to Writers. Also don't forget to `close` writer after handling all data.

Comment: "*I am new at this and i was following a tutorial*" no problem, we all started somewhere. Just take a look at link I added in my previous comment.

Comment: so i would write "out.write()" but what goes inside the parenthesis?

Comment: You need to pass there content you want to write. If you are using `JTextArea` as area for data user can write in your notepad application then you can try to use `out.write(referenceToYourArea.getText())`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose a directory

   ```
   File dir = null;
   JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
   fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
   int resp = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
   if (resp == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       dir = fc.getSelectedFile();
   }
   ```
2. Create and save file

   ```
       File file = new File(dir, "my-file.txt");
       FileWriter fw = null;
       try {
           fw = new FileWriter(file);
           fw.write("my first line\r\n");
           fw.write("my second line");
           fw.flush();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           if(fw != null) {
               try {
                   fw.close();
               } catch (IOException ex) {
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: I want the user to be able to pick the location and the text so imbedding it in the program won't work. Any other ideas